# Magento Custom URL rewrite doesn't work if request path includes uppercase letters

Tags: magento-1.7, url-rewrite

I was just facing the issue in Magento. If we use uppercase letters as request path.

Ex.

```
Request path: en-US/store-locator
Target path: stores/usa
```

Now if i try to open url as `http://MY_SITE_BASE_URLS/en-US/store-locator/`
then it doesn't redirect to Target URL.

But if i change uppercase to lowercase in request path

Ex.

```
Request path: en-us/store-locator
Target path: stores/usa
```

Now it works.

I have thousands of URL with uppercase in request path.

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 1):

If no other solutions i get then i will end up with below solution

```
$rewrite_model = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->getCollection();
    foreach ($rewrite_model as $single_rewrite):
       if(preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $single_rewrite->getRequestPath())){
       $single_rewrite->setRequestPath(strtolower($single_rewrite->getRequestPath()))->save();
        }
    endforeach;
```

This code will replace all request paths having uppercase letters into the lowercase letters.

Comment: Where do you add this code?

Comment: You can create a test.php file in root directory Or add it in any phtml ex. header.phtml for one time

Answer (score 0):

The bug comes from changements made in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Url/Rewrite.php`

```
$path = array($path);                          => $path = array(strtolower($path));
$pathBind['path' . $key] = $url;               => $pathBind['path' . $key] = strtolower($url);
$mapPenalty = array_flip(array_values($path)); => $mapPenalty = array_change_key_case(array_flip(array_values($path)));
```

As proposed [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153509/url-rewrites-does-not-work-after-update-to-1-9-3-1) a good solution is to apply to following update request on the database: `UPDATE core_url_rewrite SET request_path = LOWER(request_path)`

Another solution is to complete the changements made in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Url/Rewrite.php` replacing also the 2 occurences of `$item['request_path']` by `strtolower($item['request_path'])`

Best regards,
Olivier Blanc, Web Developper