# URL rewrites does not work after update to 1.9.3.1

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, indexing

Our redirects aren't working anymore - properply after updating to Magento 1.9.3.1.

The rewrites are still present in the URL Rewrites. If I click on one of them and save it (without editing anything), then it works again.

Any ideas how to "re-apply" them, without manually saving each and everyone?
(Reindexing does not fix the issue.

Example:

https://www.fyr-selv.dk/Briketter/SEDI-Toervebriketter/SEDI-Toervebriketter-k111-i46.html

[image: URL rewrite]

**UPDATE:**

Seem's to be 1.9.3.1 bug caused by changes to rewrites and case sensitivity.
When i save a rewrite, then `requestpath` changes all uppercase characters to lowercase. This matches the fix description in Magento changelog regarding rewrites:

`Case-sensitive variations of URL rewrites work as expected.`

But seems like the update lacks to change this for all current rewrites.

[image: Rewrites changes casing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL: `UPDATE core_url_rewrite SET request_path = LOWER(request_path)`
fixes the issue.

This is caused by Magento 1.9.3.1 changes, making request_path entries that are not all lowercase invalid.

Comment: After re-indexed the configuration back to original, how can i solve this issue?

Comment: What version are you using @zus?

Comment: Magento ver 1.9.2.3

Comment: @zus this only applies to 1.9.3.1 and above. You need to update to Magento 1.9.3.1 or above first.

Answer (score 0):

The bug comes from changements made in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Url/Rewrite.php`

```
$path = array($path);                          => $path = array(strtolower($path));
$pathBind['path' . $key] = $url;               => $pathBind['path' . $key] = strtolower($url);
$mapPenalty = array_flip(array_values($path)); => $mapPenalty = array_change_key_case(array_flip(array_values($path)));
```

The update request proposed by Michael Knudsen is probably the best solution.

Another solution is to complete the changements made in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Url/Rewrite.php` replacing also the 2 occurences of `$item['request_path']` by `strtolower($item['request_path'])`

Best regards,
Olivier Blanc, Web Developper

*Note: the same question has been asked [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107567/magento-custom-url-rewrite-doesnt-work-if-request-path-includes-uppercase-lette/307054)*